# How does Reactive Banana's mapAccum function work?

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

I have looked at a number answers to questions here on Stack Overflow trying to find a solution to my problem in using the Reactive Banana library.  All the answers use some *magic* using 'mapAccum' that I can't quite understand.  Looking at the API documentation all I find is "Efficient combination of `accumE` and `accumB`." which is not very helpful.

It seems that this function can be used to compare the values of a `Behavior` at the time of two consecutive events which is what I'd like to do.  But I not clear how to make that work.

How exactly does `mapAccum` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that

```
mapAccum :: acc -> Event t (acc -> (x, acc)) -> (Event t x, Behavior t acc)
```

so it takes an initial value `:: acc` to accumulate on, and an Event which produces a function that 
updates that accumulated value whilst producing an output value `::x`. (Typically you'd make such an event by partially applying some function via `<$>`.) 
As a result you get a new Event that fires your `x` values whenever they turn up and a Behaviour containing
your current accumulated value.

Use `mapAccum` if you have an event and you want to make a related behaviour and event.

For example in your problem domain from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327517/doing-some-basic-calculus-using-reactive-banana), suppose you have an event `eTime :: Event t Int` that fired erratically and you wanted to calculate `eDeltaTime :: Event t Int` for the differences and `bTimeAgain :: Behaviour t Int` 
for the currently used time:

```
type Time = Int
type DeltaTime = Time 

getDelta :: Time -> Time -> (DeltaTime,Time)
getDelta new old = (new-old,new)
```

I could have written that `getDelta new = \old -> (new-old,new)` to make the next step clearer:

```
deltaMaker :: Event t (Time -> (DeltaTime,Time))
deltaMaker = getDelta <$> eTime

(eDeltaT,bTimeAgain) = mapAccum 0 $ deltaMaker
```

In this case, `bTimeAgain` would be a behaviour with the same value as the events in `eTime`. This happens 
because my `getDelta` function passes `new` straight through unchanged from `eTime` to the `acc` value. 
(If I wanted `bTimeAgain` on its own, I would have used `stepper :: a -> Event t a -> Behaviour t a`.)
If I don't need `bTimeAgain`, I could just write `(eDeltaT,_) = mapAccum 0 $ deltaMaker`.

Answer (score 4):

The `mapAccum` function is very similar to the [`mapAccumL`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#g:7) function from the standard Data.List module, hence the name. The documentation on Hackage also includes a link to the [source code of `mapAccum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reactive-banana/0.7.0.1/doc/html/src/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html#mapAccum). Together with the [type signature](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reactive-banana/0.7.0.1/doc/html/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html#v%3amapAccum), this is hopefully enough information to figure out how this function works.

Then again, I could just improve the documentation. :-) But I'm not entirely clear on how to do that short of pasting the source code. The second part of the result is easy to describe by the following equation

```
snd . mapAccum acc = accumB acc . fmap (. snd)
```

But the first part does not have such a nice equation.

I could write a description in words:

> The function `mapAccum` accumulates a state of type `acc` by applying the functions contained in the second argument of type `Event t (acc -> (x,acc))`. The function returns an event whose occurrences are the values `x` and a behavior which keeps track of the accumulated state `acc`. Put differently, this is a Mealy machine, or state automaton.

but I'm not sure whether these words actually help.

Comment: Three comments, 1) I think it's great that the you, the author, are here answering questions. 2) Points free notation is hard to read if you are not sure what the function does because there are no names. 3)   Where I got lost was in understanding that the `acc` given to the function in the input event was a good place to store history of events. I kept trying to put the value I was trying to find there instead, when that should have gone in the `x` part.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: I'm using an answer so I can write formatted code

Here is my attempt at documenting the function:

---

```
mapAccum ::                  acc -- Initial Accumulation Value
  ->   Event t (acc -> (x, acc)) -- Event stream that of functions that use the previous
                                 -- accumulation value to:
                                 -- a) produce a new resulting event (x) and,
                                 -- b) updates the accumulated value (acc)
  -> (Event t x, Behavior t acc) -- fst) a stream of events from of a) above
                                 -- snd) a behavior holding the accumulated values b) above
```

This function is the analog to the `mapAccumL` function from the `Data.List` module.  It is an efficient combination of `accumE` and `accumB`. The resulting `Behavior` is useful for, among other things, for holding the history of previous events which might be needed to compute the values (x) of an event stream.

**Example**: compute the roling average of the last 5 events

```
rolingAverage :: forall t. Frameworks t => Event t Double -> Event t Double
rolingAverage inputStream = outputStream
  where
    funct x xs = (sum role / 5, role) where role = (x:init xs)
    functEvent = funct <$> inputStream -- NB: curries the first parameter in funct
    (outputStream,_) = mapAccum [0,0,0,0,0] functEvent
```