# Doing some basic calculus using Reactive Banana

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

**Setup**:

I am using Reactive Banana along with OpenGL and I have a gear that I want to spin. I have the following signals:

```
bTime :: Behavior t Int -- the time in ms from start of rendering
bAngularVelosity :: Behavior t Double -- the angular velocity
                                      -- which can be increase or
                                      -- decreased by the user
eDisplay :: Event t ()     -- need to redraw the screen
eKey :: Event t KeyState   -- user input
```

Ultimately, I need to calculate `bAngle` which is then past to the drawing function:

```
reactimate $ (draw gears) <$> (bAngle <@ eDisp)
```

The angle is easy to calculate: `a = ∫v(t) dt`

**Question**:

I *think* what I want to do is to approximate this integral as `a = ∑ v Δt` for each eDisplay event (or more often if I need to).  Is this the correct way to go about this? If so, how do I get `Δt` from `bTime`?

**See Also**:
I suspect that answer uses the `mapAccum` function.  If so, please also see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327424/how-does-reactive-bananas-mapaccum-function-work) as well.

Comment: If you like, you can avoid the calculus by letting the user chnge the interval of your bTime, in the same way as the <a href= https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/Asteroids.hs">asteroids</aa> example does.

Comment: @AndrewC, I guess [this](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/Asteroids.hs) is the link you wanted?

Comment: Yes. <facepalm>. Disadvantages: jerky at slow speeds, overloading the graphics engine at high speeds, ugly. I take my suggestion back: using the angular velocity is much more elegant.

Comment: I should have made it clear the `bTime` is wall clock time. AndrewC your first solution is what the original OpenGL author did and it was indeed not smooth, especially when processing Keyborad/Mouse inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: to answer the question, yes, you're right to use the approximation you're using, it's Euler's method of solving a first order differential equation, and is accurate enough for your purposes, particularly since the user doesn't have an absolute value for the angular velocity lying around to judge you against. Decreasing your time interval would make it more accurate, but that's not important.

You can do this in fewer, larger steps (see below), but this way seems clearest to me, I hope it is to you.

Why bother with this longer solution? This works even when `eDisplay` happens at irregular intervals, because it calculates `eDeltaT`.

Let's give ourselves a time event:

```
eTime :: Event t Int
eTime = bTime <@ eDisplay
```

To get DeltaT, we'll need to keep track of the time interval passing:

```
type TimeInterval = (Int,Int) -- (previous time, current time)
```

so we can convert them to deltas:

```
delta :: TimeInterval -> Int
delta (t0,t1) = t1 - t0
```

How should we update a time interval when we get a new one `t2`?

```
tick :: Int -> TimeInterval -> TimeInterval
tick t2 (t0,t1) = (t1,t2)
```

So let's partially apply that to the time, to give us an interval updater:

```
eTicker :: Event t (TimeInterval->TimeInterval)
eTicker = tick <$> eTime
```

and then we can `accumE`-accumulate that function on an initial time interval:

```
eTimeInterval :: Event t TimeInterval
eTimeInterval = accumE (0,0) eTicker
```

Since eTime is measured since the start of rendering, an initial `(0,0)` is appropriate.

Finally we can have our DeltaT event, by just applying (`fmap`ping) `delta` on the time interval.

```
eDeltaT :: Event t Int
eDeltaT = delta <$> eTimeInterval
```

Now we need to update the angle, using similar ideas.

I'll make an angle updater, by just turning the `bAngularVelocity` into a multiplier:

```
bAngleMultiplier :: Behaviour t (Double->Double)
bAngleMultiplier = (*) <$> bAngularVelocity
```

then we can use that to make `eDeltaAngle`: (edit: changed to `(+)` and converted to `Double`)

```
eDeltaAngle :: Event t (Double -> Double)
eDeltaAngle = (+) <$> (bAngleMultiplier <@> ((fromInteger.toInteger) <$> eDeltaT)
```

and accumulate to get the angle:

```
eAngle :: Event t Double
eAngle = accumE 0.0 eDeltaAngle
```

If you like one-liners, you can write

```
eDeltaT = delta <$> (accumE (0,0) $ tick <$> (bTime <@ eDisplay)) where
    delta (t0,t1) = t1 - t0
    tick t2 (t0,t1) = (t1,t2)

eAngle = accumE 0.0 $ (+) <$> ((*) <$> bAngularVelocity <@> eDeltaT) =
```

but I don't think that's terribly illuminating, and to be honest, I'm not sure I've got my fixities right since I've not tested this in ghci.

Of course, since I made `eAngle` instead of `bAngle`, you need

```
reactimate $ (draw gears) <$> eAngle
```

instead of your original

```
reactimate $ (draw gears) <$> (bAngle <@ eDisp)
```

Comment: Also, see my answer to your [mapAccum question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327424/how-does-reactive-bananas-mapaccum-function-work/12332814#12332814) for a nicer `mapAccum` solution to making `eDeltaT`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is to assume that `eDisplay` happens at regular time intervals, 
and consider `bAngularVelocity` to be a relative rather than absolute measure, whch would give you the really rather short solution below. [Note that this is no good if `eDisplay` is out of your control, or if it fires visibly irregularly, or varies in regularity because it will cause your gear to rotate at different speeds as the interval of your `eDisplay` changes. You'd need my other (longer) approach if that's the case.]

```
eDeltaAngle :: Event t (Double -> Double)
eDeltaAngle = (+) <$> bAngularVelocity <@ eDisplay
```

i.e. turn the `bAngularVelocity` into an adder Event that fires when you `eDisplay`, so then

```
eAngle :: Event t Double
eAngle = accumE 0.0 eDeltaAngle
```

and finally

```
reactimate $ (draw gears) <$> eAngle
```

Yes, approximating the integral as a sum is appropriate, and here I'm further approximating by making possibly slightly inaccurate assumtions about the step width, but it's clear and should be smooth as long as your `eDisplay` is more-or-less regular.